# Element with relative height changes height/jumps on scroll (mobile)

Tags: html, css, svg, layout, height

As the image below depicts, the height of the `.hero` div changes when scrolling past a certain point (Chrome, Android 6.0.1).

Here is the relevant css

```
.hero {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

That image is an svg:

```
svg {
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
```

I've come across this problem before, more often when setting height using viewport units. It's never a problem on desktop browsers (from what I can tell) and has different effects on different mobile browsers.

[image: gif depicting height problem]

I've gone through lots of different attempts at solutions (fiddling with positioning and display properties, wrapping elements in various ways, repositioning the image) but the problem persists and I don't know where to go next.

Comment: Is this `padding: .1px;` really necessary? Test your page without it.

Comment: Leftover from when I was having a margin collapse problem, this solved it initially.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but one way I solved this is by converting view height to pixel on mobile with jQuery (or pure javascript) to avoid that the value of vh changes with page link bar appears/disappears.

Here's a possible solution using jQuery:

```
h = document.documentElement.clientHeight * 0.65;
h = (h*21)/100 //calculate percent here, in this example 21%
$('#ID').css('minHeight', h+'px');
```

I know this is an old post, but I've had this same issue myself and hope this helps everyone else who encounters this :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out this is due to the address bar hiding/showing while scrolling in Chrome on mobile. The viewport essentially resizes when this happens causing anything that's sized relative to viewport to jump.

Edit: A solution to this is to set the height using JS:

```
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
windowHeight += 'px';
console.log(windowHeight);
var hero = document.getElementById('hero');
hero.style.height = windowHeight;
```